# How To Show Item With Item Given Percentage ? Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got problem on scripting the game in unity using C#.
I want to get the item which have a percent.

For example I have a `List<item> Bonus` below :

ITEM | QTY | PERCENT

1. Coin     20 100%
2. Coin     40   95%
3. Coin     300   40%
4. Coin     700  10%
5. apple    2  60%
6. Lemon    2    60%
7. orange   2    60%
8. Wood     1    90%
9. wood     2    70%
10. wood    3    50%
11. Silver Bar  1   4%
12. Fish meat   2   60%
13. Saw     1   7%
14. Rope    1   7%

The percent item show the chance to show up.

How to get 1 item from that with percentage ?
How it be in c# ? Is it enough for the detail ?

Thanks

Dennis

Comment: All items have a percent? Can you please show us your full list or give an example of your code?

Comment: Yes all item have a percent. I don't code it yet. I don't know what it will look like in code. I just store the item to the List<item> with class item.

Comment: what do you mean with getting 1 item of that with percentage? Do you need to get one item from the list?

Comment: @Basvo, Yes from 14 item above i want to get just 1 item from the list according to the chance percent.

Comment: @Basvo, the item have a value i forgot add it. I have add it now.

Comment: @DennisLiu "Yes from 14 item above i want to get just 1 item from the list according to the chance percent". If you want just one item, then, you will be able to get "Coin 20" only since the percentage is 100%.

Comment: @Hellium, i will try code below. I will give an answer after that.

Comment: @Hellium, I think i got what i want from Kardux code below.. Try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I understand your question is you'll have :

- 100% chances to get 20 coins
- plus 95% chances to get 40 coins
- plus 40% chances to get 300 coins
- ...

This way you'll have to do something like this :

```
List<items> itemsWon = new List<item>();
float randomPercentage = Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f);
for(int i = 0; i < Bonus.Count; i++)
{
    if (randomPercentage > Bonus[i].PERCENT)
    {
        itemsWon.Add(Bonus[i]);
    }
}
```

But considering your comments I'd say you only want to win 1 of those items. In this case you have to give each item and **int value** (easier than working with *floats* in this case) let's say your *PERCENT* property and do something like this :

```
items itemWon;
int totalItemsPercent = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < Bonus.Count; i++)
{
    totalItemsPercent += Bonus[i].PERCENT;
}

int percentToReach = Random.Range(0, totalItemsPercent + 1);
int itemsPercentSum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < Bonus.Count; i++)
{
    itemsPercentSum += Bonus[i].PERCENT;
    if (itemsPercentSum >= percentToReach)
    {
        itemWon = Bonus[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope those will help you. Also keep in mind posting your already produced code always help others understand what you try to achieve. Regards,

Comment: Hello @Kardux, I don't really understand the logic. I have try it. But i see that in checking condittion ( itemsPercentSum >= percentToReach ) you don't break the loop. If it not break the loop it will always give the last result from List isn't it ?

Comment: @DennisLiu Of course you need to break the loop... Kind of tired today sorry ! Thanks for pointing that out : I'll edit my answer :)